# How to remove bias when downsampling a vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, resampling, downsampling

I have a set of vectors containing some arbitrary shape like a triangle pulse with a single maxima.
I need to downsample these vectors by an integer factor.
The position of the maxima relative to the length of the vector should stay the same.

Below code shows, that when I do this, there is a `bias=-0.0085` introduced by the downsampling step which should be zero on average.

The bias doesn't seem to change much depending on the number of vectors (tried between 200 and 800 vectors)
.

I also tried different resampling functions like `downsample` and `decimate` leading to the same results.

```
datapoints = zeros(1000,800);

for ii = 1:size(datapoints,2)

    datapoints(ii:ii+18,ii) = [1:10,9:-1:1]; 
end

%downsample each column of the data
datapoints_downsampled = datapoints(1:10:end,:);

[~,maxinds_downsampled] = max(datapoints_downsampled);

[~,maxinds] = max(datapoints);

%bias needs to be zero 
bias = mean(maxinds/size(datapoints,1)-maxinds_downsampled/size(datapoints_downsampled,1))
```

[image: This graph shows, that there is a systematic bias that does not depend on the number of vectors]

This graph shows, that there is a systematic bias that does not depend on the number of vectors

**How to remove this bias? Is there a way to determine its magnitude given only one vector?**

**Where does it come from?**

Comment: How do you derive this distribution? Is the mean of the distribution not equal to the bias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues with the code:

1. Dividing the index by the length of the vector leads to a small bias: if the max is at the first element, then 1/1000 is not the same as 1/100, even though the subsampling preserved the element that contained the maximum. This needs to be corrected for by subtracting 1 before the division, and adding 1/1000 after the division.
2. Subsampling by a factor of 10 leads to a bias as well: since we're determining the integer location only, in 1/10 cases we preserve the location, in 4/10 cases we move the location in one direction, and in 5/10 cases we move the location in the other direction. The solution is to use an odd subsampling factor, or to determine the location of the maximum with sub-sample precision (this requires proper low-pass filtering before subsampling).

The code below is a modification of the code in the OP, it does a scatter plot of the error vs the location, as well as OP's bias plot. The first plot helps identify issue #2 above. I have made the subsampling factor and the offset for subsampling variables, I recommend that you play with these values to understand what is happening. I have also made the location of the maximum random to avoid a sampling bias. Note I also use `N/factor` instead of `size(datapoints_downsampled,1)`. The size of the downsampled vector is the wrong value to use if `N/factor` is not integer.

```matlab
N = 1000;
datapoints = zeros(N,800);
for ii = 1:size(datapoints,2)
    datapoints(randi(N-20)+(1:19),ii) = [1:10,9:-1:1]; 
end
factor = 11;
offset = round(factor/2);
datapoints_downsampled = datapoints(offset:factor:end,:);

[~,maxinds_downsampled] = max(datapoints_downsampled,[],1);
[~,maxinds] = max(datapoints,[],1);

maxpos_downsampled = (maxinds_downsampled-1)/(N/factor) + offset/N;
maxpos = (maxinds)/N;
subplot(121), scatter(maxpos,maxpos_downsampled-maxpos)

bias = cumsum(maxpos_downsampled-maxpos)./(1:size(datapoints,2));
subplot(122), plot(bias)
```

[image: output of code above]

Comment: The second issue is clear now, I'm trying to rephrase the first issue: Is the problem essentially, that I cannot start to sample at a point closer to 0 than index 1?

Comment: @MrVinagi: No, that bias applies to all elements equally. It is the problem of linear scaling when the scale starts at 1 rather than 0. The modified code anchors one element (at index `offset` in the original array, which ends up at index 1 in the subsampled array), such that the linear scaling keeps this element at the same fraction of array length. By anchoring this one element, all other elements that are preserved after subsampling are automatically also anchored. The goal is to scale the locations of the two arrays such that all preserved elements retain the same fraction.